# How do I follow dynamic url with DropDown Value onClick Button - why wont this work?

Tags: javascript

I have seen a post similar to this but one answer used ajax and the other form/post. I can't figure why this won't work. Grateful for any explanation - Cheers.

```
<script >
<select name="region" id="region" tags="region">
<?php echo $regionList; ?>
</select>

function getQuote(){
    e = document.getElementById("region");
    region = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    linkTarget = "http://tatgeturlpage.com' + '?region=' + region ";
    return "window.location=" + linkTarget;
}

</script>

<input type="button" onclick="getQuote()" value="Get Quote">
```

Comment: Thanks,  Changing the quotes worked - i did what you suggested but returned window.location.href="string"+appends. A quick note - I have been running the code in a WP sidebar. Using single quotes as appended strings resulted in parameters with %. Using double quotes corrected that. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Your "region" variable is read as a string rather than the selected value. So Change this line:

```
linkTarget = "http://tatgeturlpage.com' + '?region=' + region ";
```

To:

```
linkTarget = "http://tatgeturlpage.com?region=" + region;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a select statement inside of script tags. The browser will ignore them. Try moving them either above or below the script.